# SSRS Reporting Service gives an error The found version is '163'. The expected version is '176'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

When I checked the logs it is showing following error. I have updated the database from 2012 to 2016.

```
Exception caught while starting service. Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot convert to text/ntext or collate to '꿰櫌=.拤�翾...' because these legacy LOB types do not support the Unicode supplementary characters whose codepoints are U+10000 or greater. Use types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or a collation which does not have the _SC flag.
Cannot convert to text/ntext or collate to '꿰櫌=.拤�翾...' because these legacy LOB types do not support the Unicode supplementary characters whose codepoints are U+10000 or greater. Use types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or a collation which does not have the _SC flag.
Cannot convert to text/ntext or collate to '꿰櫌=.拤�翾...' because these legacy LOB types do not support the Unicode supplementary characters whose codepoints are U+10000 or greater. Use types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or a collation which does not have the _SC flag.
Cannot convert to text/ntext or collate to '꿰櫌=.拤�翾...' because these legacy LOB types do not support the Unicode supplementary characters whose codepoints are U+10000 or greater. Use types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or a collation which does not have the _SC flag.
    An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database
The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The expected version is '176'. (rsInvalidReportServerDatabase)
```

Comment: What server version are you on now and what do you mean saying " I have updated the database from 2012 to 2016"? Did you upgrade your SQL Server to 2016, or Report Server?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/acb44004-cf7a-426c-93fe-450cbbe7f531/sql-server-2012-ent-sp3-reporting-services-the-found-version-is-162-the-expected-version-is-163?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @Snowlockk, one thing when you apply the CU and upgrade your db version, and so your db's version is HIGHER than the RTM server expects, and totally different thing when the db version is lower. In the first case you just apply the next cu with the fix (it's MS's fault), in the second it's YOURS fault if your Reporting Services is upgraded and it's database not

Comment: I have installed SQL Server 2016, Database Engine and Reporting Services on the same server same time. I configured reporting server using new database and it is working fine. but when I get report server database from 2012 and upgrade it to 2016, I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the database you connect to is 2012 if we assume that you upgrade from 2012 to 2016 as you said... try to backup and restore the database to the newer version .. if accepted then reinstall the report server ....

Comment: I upgraded the database and it is still giving the same error. I took the backup from 2012 restored it to 2016 and upgraded the compatibility and then took backup and restore and it is still not working.

Comment: Please check SSRS Version if it is the same as db Engine.... go to sql server configuration manager under sql server services right click on sql server instance see version and also the same with sql server reporting services..

Comment: SQL Server Database engine and SSRS are on the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same scenario as your case, but I encountered the same error when attempting to migrate my SSRS *ReportServer* database from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 (it failed when attempting to create the reporting service in the SP2016 farm using the *New-SPRSServiceApplication* commandlet).

The problem was caused by my database server also having the **Reporting Services - SharePoint** component installed instead of just the SQL database engine.  After removing this component, I was able to create the service application and upgrade the database without issue.

The **Reporting Services - SharePoint** component should only be installed on the SharePoint application server(s) and the **Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products** should be installed on both the application server(s) and web front-end(s).